# Threads in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, callback

Well, I guess that I'm not the first who ask this, but what is the easiest way to use threads in VB.NET? I mean, I need to download some string from a remote server and then to show that string in the GUI, so I have to use some callback function to call it in the main thread. I found different approaches for this, but all seems very difficult compared to Python where (with GTK) I used something like:

```
gobject.idle_add(callback_function, parameters)
```

and "callback_function" was executed in the main thread. How I do that in VB.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example.  It may be a little more difficult than some other languages, but it's still not terribly complicated.  The following code assumes that it is within a form class (if not, you'd need to use some control or form reference to call `Invoke`):

```
 Private Sub beginDoWork()
     Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf DoWork)
     thread.Start()
 End Sub

 Public Sub DoWork()
     Dim result As String = getStringFromRemoteServer()
     workCompleted(result)
 End Sub

 Private Delegate Sub workCompletedDelegate(result As String)
 Private Sub workCompleted(result As String)
      If InvokeRequired Then
          Invoke(New workCompletedDelegate(AddressOf workCompleted(result)
          Exit Sub
      End If
      Label1.Text = result
 End Sub
```

This could be further simplified by just having `DoWork` always call `Invoke` to call `workCompleted` rather than have `workCompleted` check if the invoke is required, but the way I wrote it is a bit more encapsulated and efficient if you are ever going to do the work on the UI thread instead of a worker thread.

Comment: "if not, you'd need to use some control or form reference to call Invoke" - could you explain this, please?

Comment: Invoke and InvokeRequired are members of the Control class. Form inherits from Control, so it has those methods too. You need those methods to invoke the workCompleted method back on the UI thread. So, if your code is in the form itself, you can simply call Invoke (or Me.Invoke), but if the code is in a separate class that does not inherit from control, you will need a reference to the form or a control so you can use it to call Invoke (e.g. formOnWhichToShowResults.Invoke)

Comment: Gracias. I'm really new in this VB.Net thing and some things are harder to understand even if they're aren't new for me.